# How to identify rows that have the same value in same columns in mysql? and also i have to add condition to those rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench, procedure

```
id  bid   status   time
1   c1   close   2019.10.11
2   c2   close   2019.12.12
3   c2   open    2019.12.11
4   c3   close   2019.12.14
```

here I want to capture both c2 s and I have to find the time difference

Comment: What should your output look like?

Comment: Can a bid value ever have more than one open or close date?

Comment: Either a self inner join, or a group by.

Comment: the output should retrieve both c2 records which has the open and close with time difference of one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is `join`:

```
select to.*, tc.time as close_time,
       datediff(tc.time, to.time)
from t to join
     t tc
     on to.bid = tc.bid and
        to.status = 'open' and
        tc.status = 'close';
```

Comment: In the same query how can i check previous record has the same bid ???

Comment: @V2rson . . . Please ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic.

Comment: i hv posted a new question

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists`

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.bid = t.bid and t1.time <> t.time);
```

Comment: here i have to get the time difference  & i have to check the current record and previous record has to be close and open  !